# How to cast an integer to a constant void pointer?

Tags: c++

```
int getNumber(){
   int number;
   cin >> number;
   return number;
}
```

```
const void * getPointer(){
   const void *p = (const void *)getNumber();
   return p;
}
```

Gives me an error:

> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

and the console crashes

Comment: `int` is likely 4 bytes on your system while `void*` is 8 bytes. Use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` to guarantee a pointer size instead.

Comment: Why do you want "to cast an integer to a const void pointer", exactly?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to pass it as an argument to a function which can perform the sum of two integers numbers and also it can perform the sum of two points

Comment: Sum of two pointers? This is illegal in C/C++ and makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @bloody I use overloading at a given time

Comment: If a function wants to "perform the sum of two integers", then why exactly can't the function take two integers as a parameter? This is C++, not C. A specialized template function can be easily and safely written to do this without resorting to this kind of unsafe, bad programming practice.

Comment: const void* p = new int{ getNumber() }; // would create space on stack for the received variable, and this pointer could be used further.

Comment: Since this is not a program that can be executed (no entry point!) I fail to see how it can "crash the console"

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings i have edited the post

Comment: Now it's a completely different question :(

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings well, I think I will leave it. I just wanted to know how to make that cast

Comment: @BUG: I don't understand what you intend to achieve by creating an `int`, passing a pointer to it around as a `const void*`, then type punning it to a `Point` (a class of two `double`s), which is not only a completely different type, but doesn't even have the same size. That just makes no sense.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I want to achieve the polymorphism

Comment: @BUG But those types are not polymorphic. They are completely unrelated. You can't change the type of an object to just anything you want at any time via a cast. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings my mistake, not polymorphism. I wanted to say dependency injection

Comment: @BUG You can deploy whatever buzzwords you like; you still can't take an `int` and pretend it's a totally unrelated type with a different size. Period.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

getNumber() returns a copy. You cast the copy to a pointer. (There is a difference between the copy and the address of the copy, which is what the pointer should be)

```
int nb = getNumber();
const void *cp_void = (const void *)nb; // this will not yield the expected result.
int *p_nb = &nb; // memory adress to variable .. but variable will go out of scope
```

As the comments suggest just dynamically allocating the int is not the answer and there is a very likely a design flaw (in the code not shown).

The two snippets shown getNumber() and getPointer() are not enough for us to comment or improve on the rest of the program.

Comment: The shown program doesn't take a reference nor a pointer to a temporary object.

Comment: im not sure we are looking at the same thing then - the first line in getPointer() . .calls the getNumber() function which returns a temporary value which will go out of scope once the function ends and as such the 'memory address' will no longer be availalbe.. i might be wrong though

Comment: @eerorika ```int getNumber(){  int *number = new int;  *number = 10;return number;}```
it works like this

Comment: @BUG Keep in mind when doing dynamic allocation (new) .. your objects will not be deallocated until you explicitly delete them yourself .. and as such they are considered memory leaks.. that is also the reason for modern cpp advocating for the use of smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @BUG The program in your comment is ill-formed. Furthermore, it doesn't convert int to a pointer, but rather converts pointer to an int which is opposite of what you were asking about.

Comment: @eerorika ```int * getNumber(){  int *number = new int; cin >> *number; return number;} ``` and it works like this. Is this a good approach?

Comment: @BUG that one is well defined but I wouldn't describe it as a good solution for anything. Why do you think you need to dynamically allocate an int?

Comment: @eerorika is it ok to copy my complete code inside the question?

Comment: This is incorrect. The integer itself is being cast to a pointer type. That doesn't involve taking the address of anything.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings- you are both right.. i somehow totally missed that it was the 'variable' and not the adress of the variable which was being cast.

Answer (score 5):

> How to cast an integer to a constant void pointer?

Start with an integer type that is wide enough to represent all pointer values. `std::intptr_t` is such type.  If you want to convert from  a narrower type, then you can convert it to a wider type first. Then use reinterpret_cast.

> and the console crashes

The shown program is not the cause of that crash.

---

Note that converting an integer to a pointer is an advanced technique that is rarely needed. If you are a beginner, then you likely are facing the [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).